# JXA : "Cant Create duplicate variable" after second & more runs

Tags: javascript, macos

my aim was to create a variable from chrome tab. Below is the script. When I run first time, it works fine, but after that every time on run, gives error : Error: SyntaxError: Can't create duplicate variable: varChr

```
let chromeApp = Application("Google Chrome");
    chrDoc = chromeApp.windows[0].activeTab;
    varTitle = chrDoc.name();
    varURL = chrDoc.url()

let varChr =  "- " + varTitle + " \n\t " + varURL;
```

Any suggestions wud be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
varChr = ChrVal()

function ChrVal() {
let chromeApp = Application("Google Chrome");
    chrDoc = chromeApp.windows[0].activeTab;
    varTitle = chrDoc.name();
    varURL = chrDoc.url()
    return "- " + varTitle + " \n\t " + varURL;
}
```

This works, converted into a function which makes it a local value, and not a global

Is this correct ?